# Vector space subspace of field of polynomial problem

Tags: linear-algebra

Is the set $W=(f(x)\in P(F): f(x)=0$ or $f(x)$ has degree $n$) a subspace of $P(F)$ if $n\geq 1$?

In the answer it is said that no, because addition is not closed.

But shouldn't it be closed? 
If both $f(x)=0$ and $g(x)=0$ then $(f+g)(x)=0$

If $f(x)=0$ and $g(x)$ has degree $n$ then $(f+g)(x)$ has degree n.

If both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ have degree n, then $(f+g)(x)$ has degree n.

So how is it not closed under addition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that $f(x)=x^n+x$, and $g(x)=-x^n$ are both in your space, but their sum is not.

Comment: Thank you! I missed the obvious it seems now, lol.